# AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'unique_object_name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

greeting to all

I want to add a Dense layer to my deep learning project

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
model.add(layers.Dense(500, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
```

but this error has occurred.
Does anyone have a solution?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MobileNetV3Large' from 'keras.applications.mobilenet_v3' (C:\Users\mostafa.f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\applications\mobilenet_v3\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Please never add errors as an image, but raw text. Try to import Keras libraries from TensorFlow like: `from tensorflow.keras import layers`

Comment: ok i try  to keep it in mind and thank you for you'r answer, i did that but a new error has occurred 'ImportError: cannot import name 'MobileNetV3Large' from 'keras.applications.mobilenet_v3'

Comment: Change all your `import from keras` to `import from tensorflow.keras` and if it didn't work, update your question.

Comment: I do that but same error

Comment: Maybe you can do : `from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV3Large`

Comment: The problem has solved with reinstall python and packages, thank to every body